# OpenZepellin does not use inmutable in some contracts. Why?

Tags: solidity, etherscan, openzeppelin

I am reading the contracts of OpenZeppelin, in particular the ERC20.sol.
I see that they could use immutable in the case of the name and symbol, but they are not using its.
They they prefear a stard private variable instead of inmutable?

```
    mapping(address => uint256) private _balances;

    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint256)) private _allowances;

    uint256 private _totalSupply;

    string private _name;
    string private _symbol;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because immutable variables can not have a non-value type i.e string here check out [docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/contracts.html?highlight=Immutable%20#:%7E:text=Not%20all%20types%20for%20constants%20and%20immutables%20are%20implemented%20at%20this%20time.%20The%20only%20supported%20types%20are%20strings%20(only%20for%20constants)%20and%20value%20types.) for more information on same.
Check out docs to find out more about all [value type](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.9/types.html#value-types).

Comment: But, why is non-value type? You can use immutable with strings.

Comment: As mentioned in [docs] (https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/contracts.html?highlight=Immutable%20#:~:text=Not%20all%20types%20for%20constants%20and%20immutables%20are%20implemented%20at%20this%20time.%20The%20only%20supported%20types%20are%20strings%20(only%20for%20constants)%20and%20value%20types.) "Not all types for constants and immutables are implemented at this time. The only supported types are strings (only for constants) and value types."